# Получить имя контакта из телефонного номера

Tags: android

При получении звонка с неизвестного номера, как можно узнать имя звонящего или данные звонящего телефона ?

Comment: Минутка рекламы: [2GIS Dialer](http://apps.2gis.ru/dialer) решает в точности эту задачу, находя по определяемому номеру данные организации из своей базы. В базе есть практически все организации городов, где есть 2GIS, но нет частных лиц. Например, у меня в Новосибирске определялся телефон кадрового агенства из Питера.

Comment: 1. Создать свою базу данных абонентов. 2. Делать запрос к своей базе каждый раз, когда надо узнать что-либо по номеру телефона.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обычно эту информацию имеет только оператор связи. Засим вам надо или с ним кооперироваться или делать свою базу данных, кою вам придётся наполнять телефонами и данными, как делают уже некоторые приложения типа антиколлекторских.

Comment: спасибо $%^&*^% :)

Comment: вапрос: вазможна ли при получение звонка узнатьимя на кого зарегистрирован телефон (при покупки телефона пользователь вводит свое имя)

Comment: Если номера звонящего нет в адресной книге телефона, то нет.